# Finding the distribution of a field in a list of objects?

Tags: python, django

I have a list of objects. Each object has a field called `grade` whose value is between 0 and 5. Now I want to see the distribution of this field across my list of objects. Is there any way to find it?

I know I can iterate over the whole objects and find it out but I don't want to do that.

Comment: What do you want, a list of the counts of each unique value? This kind of stuff is better done by the database than your program.

Comment: I want to see how many objects have value of the field grade
as 0, 1, 2 .. 5. e.g; Out of total 100 objects in the list 30 have value of grade as 4, 30 have 2, and 40 have 0. So a distribution of the field. I'm not storing this distribution I just want to check the how the variable is behaving.

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, using a table `Table` with a `grade` column you need something like this:

```
counts = Table.objects.annotate(count=Count("grade", distinct=True)
```

This adds a `count` attribute to each member of the `counts` query set, which you can access just like a regular database column.